# How to select multiple circular DIV elements?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a webpage that displays a circle broken up into quadrants and allows the user to select one or more of the quadrants by clicking on them.  After a user clicks a quadrant to select it, the quadrant would change color.

Below is a snippet of HTML that displays the upper two quadrants.

Using HTML, CSS, and/or JavaScript, how I can update my code to actually do this?

I've tried various solutions, but the closest I got was being able to select a single quadrant at a time and changing the background color of the enclosing square DIV, not the circular quadrant's color.

```html
<div style="display:inline-block;
                position:relative;
                height:500px;
                width:500px;">
  <div style="position:absolute;
                    top:0;
                    left:0;">
    F1
  </div>
  <div style="background:#CCC;
                    border:2px solid #000;
                    border-radius:500px 0 0 0;
                    color:#000;
                    height:500px;
                    width:500px;">
  </div>
</div>

<div style="display:inline-block;
                position:relative;
                height:500px;
                width:500px;">
  <div style="position:absolute;
                    top:0;
                    right:0;">
    F2
  </div>
  <div style="background:#CCC;
                    border:2px solid #000;
                    border-radius:0 500px 0 0;
                    color:#000;
                    height:500px;
                    width:500px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? changing background color an click is very basic and there are thousands of tutorials on this. If you have a specific problem, then show us, what you did and what doesn't work

Comment: Post what you have tried, otherwise we're just solving the problem for you instead of showing you what was wrong with what you tried.

Comment: Temani Afif answered my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a simple 2x2 grid using flex, grid, inline-block, etc and use border radius on the container instead of the elements.

Then you can easily add JS code to change background-color of element on click.

```js
$('.box > div').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('select');
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box>div {
  height: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.box>div.f1 {
  border-left: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  background: blue;
}

.box>div.f2 {
  border-right: 0;
  border-top: 0;
  background: red;
}

.box>div.f4 {
  border-right: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  background: green;
}

.box>div.f3 {
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  background: orange;
}

.box>div.select {
  background: #111;
}

.box>div:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="f1">F1</div>
  <div class="f2">F2</div>
  <div class="f3">F3</div>
  <div class="f4">F4</div>
</div>
```